# URL of Undefined When deleting a Record in MongoDB Angular Application

Tags: angular, mongodb

When I press the "delete" button in my program, I am getting an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIS7W.jpg) that comes up when it tries to read the database to delete the record. When I switch over to my network tab in Chrome Developer Tools, I get a server status of "failed". How am I able to make this error go away and have my program delete things properly from my database in MongoDB?

I have tried to remove `/responses/` from `/responses/:id` and that only yielded the same results.

This is what my code looks like in the component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Response } from '../response.model';
import { ResponseService } from '../response.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, Params } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-response-detail',
  templateUrl: './response-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./response-detail.component.css']
})
export class ResponseDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  response: Response;
  id: string;

  constructor(private responseService: ResponseService,
              private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private router: Router){ }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(
      (params: Params) => {
        this.id = params['id'];
        this.response = this.responseService.getResponse(this.id);
      }
    );
  }

  onEditResponse() {
    this.router.navigate(['edit'], {relativeTo: this.route});
  }

  onDelete(responseId:string){
    this.responseService.deleteResponse(responseId);
  }

}
```

Here is my service (This is only the condensed version):

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Response } from './response.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ResponseService {
  responseSelectedEvent = new EventEmitter<Response>();
  responseListChangedEvent = new Subject<Response[]>();
  private responsesUpdated = new Subject<Response[]>();
  maxResponseId: number;
  responses: Response[] = [];
  id: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient ) {
    this.maxResponseId = this.getMaxId();
  }

  deleteResponse(responseId: string) {
    this.http.delete("http://localhost:3000/response/" + responseId)
      .subscribe(() => {
        const updatedResponses = this.responses.filter(response => response.id !== responseId);
        this.responses = updatedResponses;
        this.responsesUpdated.next([...this.responses]);
      });
  }
```

Then this is my js file.

```
router.delete("/responses/:id", (req, res, next)=>{
    Response.deleteOne({ _id: req.params.id }).then(result => {
      console.log(result);
      res.status(200).json({ message: "Response deleted!"});
    });
  });
```

The expected output should be that the record is deleted from the database when you press the delete button. But, what I am getting in return is `http://localhost:3000/responses/undefined`.

Comment: did you pass value for responseId? responseId is undefined

Comment: Are you getting a valid `responseId` in your `onDelete` method in the component ?